# How to create a function, get input from a data frame and output to a text file using R?

Tags: r

I need to create a function called `CarPFunction` that will take `CarP` (data frame below) as input and store on separate lines, tab-delimited the `manufacturer`, `model` and `year` of the cars that use more than 20 gallons gas in the city in a .txt file.

```
manufacturer               model displ year cyl      trans drv cty hwy
        audi                  a4   1.8 1999   4   auto(l5)   f  18  29
        audi                  a4   1.8 1999   4 manual(m5)   f  21  29
        audi                  a4   2.0 2008   4 manual(m6)   f  20  31
        audi                  a4   2.0 2008   4   auto(av)   f  21  30
        audi                  a4   2.8 1999   6   auto(l5)   f  16  26
        audi                  a4   2.8 1999   6 manual(m5)   f  18  26
        audi                  a4   3.1 2008   6   auto(av)   f  18  27
        audi          a4 quattro   1.8 1999   4 manual(m5)   4  18  26
        audi          a4 quattro   1.8 1999   4   auto(l5)   4  16  25
        audi          a4 quattro   2.0 2008   4 manual(m6)   4  20  28
        audi          a4 quattro   2.0 2008   4   auto(s6)   4  19  27
        audi          a4 quattro   2.8 1999   6   auto(l5)   4  15  25
        audi          a4 quattro   2.8 1999   6 manual(m5)   4  17  25
        audi          a4 quattro   3.1 2008   6   auto(s6)   4  17  25
        audi          a4 quattro   3.1 2008   6 manual(m6)   4  15  25
        audi          a6 quattro   3.1 2008   6   auto(s6)   4  17  25
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't have access to the original data, here is an answer that illustrates how to write a file of make, model, and MPG for cars that have more than 20 MPG from the `mtcars` data set.

First, we have to extract the make and model from the row names, and clean up a few of the rows.

```
makeModel <- rownames(mtcars)
strings <- strsplit(makeModel," ")
# clean the data so each row has make and model
strings[[2]] <- c("Mazda","RX4 Wagon")
strings[[4]] <- c("AMC","Hornet 4 Drive")
strings[[5]] <- c("AMC","Hornet Sportabout")
strings[[6]] <- c("Plymouth","Valiant")
strings[[7]] <- c("Plymouth","Duster 360")
strings[[24]] <- c("Chevrolet","Camaro Z28")
```

Next, we add `make`, `model` and `year` to the data frame. Note that all the cars in `mtcars` are from the 1973 - 74 model year.

```
# add make and model to data frame
mtcars$make <- unlist(lapply(1:length(strings),function(x){strings[[x]][1]}))
mtcars$model <- unlist(lapply(1:length(strings),function(x){strings[[x]][2]}))
mtcars$year <- 1973
```

Now we write a function to read the data, subset on `mpg > 20` and write only `make`, `model`, `year` and `mpg` to an output file, tab separated.

```
carpFunction <- function(x,outfile = "./mtcarsSubset.txt"){
     outputData <- x[x$mpg > 20,c(12:14,1)]
     write.table(outputData,file=outfile,sep="\t",row.names = FALSE)
}
```

We call the function to create the output file.

```
carpFunction(mtcars)
```

...and the output, when viewed in a text editor such as UltraEdit where we can see the tabs as `»`, looks like this.

```
"make"»"model"»"year"»"mpg"
"Mazda"»"RX4"»1973»21
"Mazda"»"RX4 Wagon"»1973»21
"Datsun"»"710"»1973»22.8
"AMC"»"Hornet 4 Drive"»1973»21.4
"Merc"»"240D"»1973»24.4
"Merc"»"230"»1973»22.8
"Fiat"»"128"»1973»32.4
"Honda"»"Civic"»1973»30.4
"Honda"»"Corolla"»1973»33.9
"Honda"»"Corona"»1973»21.5
"Fiat"»"X1-9"»1973»27.3
"Porsche"»"914-2"»1973»26
"Lotus"»"Europa"»1973»30.4
"Volvo"»"142E"»1973»21.4
```

Note, now that the OP has posted data we still shouldn't provide a complete answer for homework questions. The techniques used in this answer can be used to answer the homework question.

To demonstrate this, we'll provide everything except the code within the `carPFunction()` function.

```
textFile <- "manufacturer|model |displ |year |cyl |trans |drv |cty|hwy 
audi|a4|1.8|1999|4|auto(l5)  |f|18|29         
audi|a4|1.8|1999|4|manual(m5)|f|21|29         
audi|a4|2.0|2008|4|manual(m6)|f|20|31         
audi|a4|2.0|2008|4|auto(av)  |f|21|30         
audi|a4|2.8|1999|6|auto(l5)  |f|16|26         
audi|a4|2.8|1999|6|manual(m5)|f|18|26         
audi|a4|3.1|2008|6|auto(av)  |f|18|27         
audi|a4 quattro|1.8|1999|4|manual(m5)|4|18|26 
audi|a4 quattro|1.8|1999|4|auto(l5)  |4|16|25 
audi|a4 quattro|2.0|2008|4|manual(m6)|4|20|28 
audi|a4 quattro|2.0|2008|4|auto(s6)  |4|19|27 
audi|a4 quattro|2.8|1999|6|auto(l5)  |4|15|25 
audi|a4 quattro|2.8|1999|6|manual(m5)|4|17|25 
audi|a4 quattro|3.1|2008|6|auto(s6)  |4|17|25 
audi|a4 quattro|3.1|2008|6|manual(m6)|4|15|25 
audi|a6 quattro|3.1|2008|6|auto(s6)  |4|17|25 
"
cars <- read.csv(text=textFile,sep="|",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

carPFunction <- function(x,outfile = "./carPSubset.txt"){
     # code to exactly solve homework 
     # goes here
}
carPFunction(cars)
```

... and the output with `»` as placeholder for a horizontal tab:

```
"manufacturer"»"model"»"year"
"audi"»"a4"»1999
"audi"»"a4"»2008
```